# pass bash regex pattern as a part of bigger regex pattern in awk

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, scripting

I am trying to do this in my script:

```
 CONTEXT_PAT1="\[[gG][lL][oO][bB][aA][lL]\]"

 awk -v pat1="$CONTEXT_PAT1" 'f;/^[:space:]*pat1[:space:]*$/{f=1}' ${CONFIG_FL}
```

When I run it in debug mode, I see this happening:

```
 ++ awk -v 'pat1=\[[gG][lL][oO][bB][aA][lL]\]' 'f;/^[:space:]*pat1[:space:]*$/{f=1}
```

Expected is:

```
 ++ awk -v 'pat1=\[[gG][lL][oO][bB][aA][lL]\]' 'f;/^[:space:]\[[gG][lL][oO][bB][aA][lL]\][:space:]*$/{f=1}
```

How can I achieve this ? I have gone through some articles here in stackoverflow

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

But this is when you use the regex as it is to awk, but not consider it part of a bigger regex.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: Could you please add some input and expected output samples in your post too, so that we could test our code(s) too.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Edit: To get the output that you expect from your `sh -x` trace, read this answer. To create proper awk code, read @ghoti's answer.

`$` expansion does not happen inside single quotes (`'`), but does in double quotes `"`. Try:

```
CONTEXT_PAT1="\[[gG][lL][oO][bB][aA][lL]\]"

awk 'f;/^[:space:]'"${CONTEXT_PAT1}"'[:space:]*$/{f=1}' "${CONFIG_FL}"
```

The shell will not expand *pat1 for you. Assuming that what you mean by "debug mode" is `sh -x`

Comment: not sure if I am missing something here, `-v` is not having any values here?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 fixed ;)

Comment: May I suggest that you do NOT do this?  It's often considered bad practice to embed variables in this way. Passing variables in using `-v` is much safer. When you do things as this answer suggests, something small and unexpected to cause your script to break, or worse, vulnerable.

Comment: @ghoti True, but this fulfills the expected output of `sh -x` in the question.

Comment: Do NOT do this, it is the wrong approach. Code that produces the expected output given some specific input is the **starting** point to a correct answer, not the end point.

Answer (score 4):

You CAN in fact match against a variable or a function. It's only the implicit shorthand where a RE is intended to match the whole line where there is no mechanism to embed a variable in a larger RE. So you might want to be EXplicit, and use the RE operator, `~`.

For your example, I'd go with something like this:

```
$ pat1="[[][gG][lL][oO][bB][aA][lL][]]"
$ awk -v pat1="$pat1" 'BEGIN{re="^[[:space:]]*" pat1 "[[:space:]]*$"} f; $0~re{f=1}' file.cfg
```

Or even,

```
$ awk -v pat1="$pat1" 'f; $0~sprintf("^[[:space:]]*%s[[:space:]]*$",pat1) {f=1}' file.cfg
```

I might even simplify the use of this thing further by saving you the hassle of passing in a case insensitive regex:

```
$ pat1="global"
$ awk -v pat1="$pat1" 'f; tolower($0) ~ sprintf("^[[:space:]]*[[]%s[]][[:space:]]*$",tolower(pat1)) {f=1}' file.cfg
```

Comment: This is the correct answer as long as your regepx (and it **is** a regexp, not a "pattern" - patterns are for quilts and sweaters, in software we should try to be clear and specific about the constructs we're using) doesn't contain backslashes that you do not want interpreted. If it does then pass the regexp in the argument list. See http://cfajohnson.com/shell/cus-faq-2.html#Q24.

Comment: @ghoti it doesn't work actually. I'm putting the debug lines (and by that I mean `sh -x`). For the first one: `++ awk -v 'pat1=[[][gG][lL][oO][bB][aA][lL][]]' 'BEGIN{re="^[[:space:]]*" pat1 "[[:space:]]*$"} f; $0~re{f=1}' /etc/samba/smb.conf`. For the second one: `++ awk -v 'pat1=[[][gG][lL][oO][bB][aA][lL][]]' 'f; $0~sprintf("^[[:space:]]*%s[[:space:]]*$",pat1) {f=1}' /etc/samba/smb.conf` and I'm certain the third one expand either ...

Comment: @dig_123, bear in mind that `sh -x` only shows you how the shell line is being expanded, it doesn't help you debug the awk script or see how your data are being interpreted. When I wrote this, I used sample input that I created since there was none in your question, and my code worked with that. If you can add to your question sample input that it *doesn't* work with, I'd be happy to help figure out why.